# Как распространить видимость глобальной переменной на два файла?

Tags: c++, файлы, переменные, область-видимости

Собственно как это сделать? Язык - С++. Желательно с примером, для лучшего понимания. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так:

В файле `var.h`:

```
extern int variable;
```

В файле `var.cpp`:

```
int variable;
```

В любом другом файле подключаете `var.h` и используете `variable`.